# What do a network route and a host route look like in a routing table?

Tags: routing, route

In the routing table output by `route`, What do  a network route   and a host route look like? From https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-a-routing-table/

> Network Route: A route (path) to a specific Network ID in the
>   internetwork.
>
> Host Route : A route to a specific internetwork address (Network ID
>   and Host ID). Host routes allow intelligent routing decisions to be
>   made for each network address. Host routes are used to create custom
>   routes to control or optimize specific types of network traffic.

Are a network route and a host route  related to   flag:

- H (target is a host)
- G (use gateway)?

Are a network route and a host route  related to whether the next hop is a gateway or a local network interface?

Thanks.

Comment: This is under the context of understanding the usage of `route` command. If this question is posted on networkingengineering.se, it will be closed as OS specific. They   want nothing about  OS, user programs, or application level.

Answer (score 4):

A "host route" is route to a single host, a "network route" is route to a network of more than one host. The only difference is really the netmask of the target.
`192.168.1.0/32` is only one address, so a route to it is a host route; but `192.168.1.0/24` is a block of 256 addresses, and a route to it is a network route.

That's completely orthogonal to if the next hop is a local network interface, or one reached by a gateway.

(Though any locally connected network would probably have more than one address, so you might as well have a route for the whole network. Point-to-point links might be an exception, of course.)